In Psalms 56:10, why does David address "God" and "Jehohvah" separately?
A recent question, Why does David 'praise word' in both Elohim and Jehovah? asks about the use of "word" here without a qualifier (e.g. "his word").

In God will I praise [his] word: in the LORD will I praise [his] word.
— Psalm 56:10 (KJV) - Interlinear

A possibly more interesting aspect of this verse is that David says this twice, "in God (Elohim)" and "in Jehovah (YHWH)".
From a pre-christian perspective, how would people of the time have understood seemingly treating God and Jehovah separately?

It is notable,  as the OP made clear in a prior question on SE-C, that both names (Elohim and Jehovah) are also stated in regard to the burning bush observed by Moses about four hundred years previous to David's psalm.

@NigelJ how are you dating Exodus/Psalm 56?

@AviAvraham Houston Christian University - Bible History Timeline.

The OT contains numerous titles of God such as:

El-Shaddai, Gen 17:1, 28:3, 35:11, 43:14, 48:3, etc
El-Elyone, Gen 14:18, 19, 20, 22, Ps 57:2, 78:35
Adonai - hundreds of times
YHWH - hundreds of times
YHWH Nissi - Ex 17:15
etc (there are many more)

Now, the point of this is to show that, in poetic Biblical Hebrew, these name are often used synthetically in Hebrew parallelism.  Here is a sample:

Ps 57:2 - I cry out to God Most High [Elyone], to God who fulfills his purpose for me.
Ps 78:35 - They remembered that God was their rock, the Most High [Elyone] God their redeemer.
Ps 48:8 - As we have heard, so we have seen in the city of the LORD of Hosts, in the city of our God: God will establish her forever.
Ps 84:3 - Even the sparrow finds a home, and the swallow a nest for herself, where she may lay her young, at your altars, O LORD of hosts, my King and my God.
Isa 1:24 - Therefore the Lord GOD of Hosts, the Mighty One of Israel, declares: “Ah, I will be relieved of My foes and avenge Myself on My enemies.
Isa 5:16 - But the LORD of hosts is exalted in justice, and the Holy God shows himself holy in righteousness.

... there are many more.  Therefore, I see Ps 56;10 in this light - a Hebrew synthetic parallelism.

Jah-ua'vey-ha is the father.
David says in Psalm 110 that the LORD said unto my Lord...
He said God Almighty said unto my God, sit thou at my right hand

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
